# O que são "expressões" em javascript?

Tags: javascript, expressões

Eu gostaria de saber o que são "expressões" e "expressões primárias" em javascript. O site da [mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#express%C3%B5es) traz como exemplo de expressão **x = 7** e **3 + 4**, porém na parte de "expressões primárias" ele mostra o **"*this*"** que é uma palavra reservada e que não tem nada a ver com **x = 7** ou **3 + 4** e mostra o ***"()"*** (operador de agrupamento).Se possível também explicar o que é "expressão lado esquerdo" que também é apresentado no site.

Comment: A pergunta marcada como duplicata já responde o que é uma expressão, mas só para completar em relação ao `this` – pense em **expressão** como tudo aquilo que **retorna um valor** quando é avaliado. Desse modo, o `this` (como qualquer outra variável), ao ser “lido” pelo _runtime_, irá retornar o valor do _binding_. O `this` nada mais é que uma variável, considerada “especial” por sempre estar implícita ao contexto de execução.

Comment: no próprio link explica *"Uma expressão consiste em qualquer unidade válida de código que é resolvida como um valor"*, ou seja, algo que resolvido gera um valor, podendo atribuir ou não a uma variável esse valor, como os exemplos que colocou `x = 7` o valor é 7, atribuido a `x` e aqui `3 + 4` o valor é 7 mas não foi atribuído, provavelmente vai ser usado como parte de uma expressão maior, por exemplo `if (y == 3+ 4)` ou `if (y > 3 + 4)`, etc. O link é bem detalhado, talvez falte um exemplo de expressão à esquerda, como `x += 2` ou seja calcula x+2 e atribui a esquerda o mesmo que `x = x + 2`